# Custom adapter notifyDataSetChanged() causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a notifications listview.And I need to refresh listview content with short intervals. But when I call notifyDataSetChanged() there is no exception until scroll bottom. After scroll bottom it throws  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. There is my code:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
       init();
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               notificationsListView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
               Log.i("Checking", "...");
           }
       });
   }
```

Adapter.java

```
public class NotificationsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   RealmResults<myNotification> notifications;
   Context context;
   public NotificationsListViewAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<myNotification> notifications){
       this.context = context;
       this.notifications = notifications;
   }
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       Log.e("NOT SIZE ADAPTER COUNT", String.valueOf(notifications.size()));
       return notifications.size();
   }

   @Override
   public myNotification getItem(int position) {
       return notifications.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public int getViewTypeCount() {
       Log.e("NOT SZE ADPTR VT COUNT", String.valueOf(notifications.size()));
       return notifications.size();
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {

       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View notificationsRowView = convertView;

       // i am not posting getView() it is 400 row code and im sure error is not coming from getView()

       return notificationsRowView;
   }
}
```

Btw init function;

```
void init(){
     realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     notifications = realm.where(myNotification.class).findAllSorted("messageID",Sort.DESCENDING);
     notificationsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notificationActivity_notificationsListView);
     adapter = new NotificationsListViewAdapter(NotificationActivity.this,notifications);
     notificationsListView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: post "init()" method and adapter class

Comment: i posted what did you ask me 2 days ago @an_droid_dev

Comment: here you have a lot of problem. Firstly you never set adapter to listview. Secondly "runOnUiThread" is not needed because you are just in mainThread and thirdly i don't understand why you cal again "notifyDataSetChanged" inside "runOnUiThread" without never set adapter to listview @madProgrammer

Comment: my mistake,  i copied wrong line to here... . I was setting adapter. Otherwise how could i scroll down as i pointed at my questiıon :) i was using thread to check adapter for any changes in listview for shot intervals. But still none of your solutions answering "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" problem...@an_droid_dev

Comment: are you sure in your getView have not some strange position increment? @madProgrammer

Comment: I am sure. Why would i make any increment there? :D @an_droid_dev

Comment: maybe for error of course :D , but "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" meaning this

Comment: :D unfortunately i m not doing it :D Listview coming at first. if i get new item , notdifydatasetchanged() runs then if i scroll down its crashes...@an_droid_dev

Comment: Have you got other threads that point to the same arraylist that are you passed into adapter and than maybe modify it?  @madProgrammer

Comment: i m working with realm mb u noticed. When i got notification it automatycally added to arraylist. But notifydatasetonchange must handle it. Isn it ? @an_droid_dev

Comment: Yes i notice that. I suggest to create an arraylist into adapter and add all entries from arraylist from realm. So , when you update your adapter create a method that clear your arraylist into adapter and add all entries into so call notifydatasetchanged. @madProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your code incorrectly calculates `getCount()` inside adapter.
Post your elements' storage and adapter code in order to be sure.

Comment: Actually `getCount` returns exact array size. I mean it is increasing and decreasing by operation, I have tested it with logs. But I've just noticed that if I increase my `getViewTypeCount()` returning value by 1 , it allows me add 1 item if I add 2nd it crashes. So I think problem is with `getViewTypeCount` method. And it is returning `getCount()` ... but not changing dynamicly...

Comment: @madProgrammer.ok I will check asap